# How do I fix a mismatching type error when returning the result of a stream collector?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming

I have this piece of code:

```
public static List <java.util.Date> map(List <Object[]> queryRows) {

  List <Object> list = Arrays.asList(queryRows);
  List <Object> list2 = Arrays.asList(list.get(0));

  return ((List) list2.get(0))
        .stream()
        .map(x -> new java.util.Date(((java.sql.Timestamp) x).getTime()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

but I have this compilation error:

```
Required type:List<java.util.Date>
Provided:Object
```

Comment: What is `Timestamp`? There is no constructor for such object in `java.util.Date` (which is also deprecated).

Comment: Please fix the question title: it’s unclear how it related to the question (as far as I can tell it’s entirely unrelated). Furthermore, please don’t include tags again in the question title. Just make your title a sentence briefly describing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the elements are of type `Timestamp`, you should avoid using the raw type(the reason why the type of Stream is not inferred and everything ends up being inferred as `Object`) and work with

```
return ((List<java.sql.Timestamp>) list2.get(0))
            .stream()
            .map(x -> new Date(x.getTime()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
List <Object> list = Arrays.asList(queryRows);
List <Object> list2 = Arrays.asList(list.get(0));

return  Arrays.asList(list2.get(0))
          .stream()
          .map(x -> new java.util.Date(((java.sql.Timestamp) x).getTime()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This should work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Adding information about *why* this works, and the questioner’s approach didn’t, would improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the return type in the lambda expression to `List<Date>`:

```
return ((List<Date>) list2.get(0))
                .stream()
                .map(x-> new Date((x).getTime()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an import statement or change Date to java.util.Date. Another issue is you should not have white space between - >. It should be *->*

Comment: The missing import doesn’t explain OP’s error message. That is caused by incorrect casting.